# Вопрос про структуры данных

Tags: c#, c++

Не судите строго. Такой вопрос, зачем знать структуры данных(list,map,array и т.д.) помимо ответов на вопросы на собеседовании, если можно использовать БД? Можете привести примеры использования структур данных? Где структуры данных будут лучше БД?

Comment: Так в БД используются те же самые структуры данных, и вы должны понимать их особенности, чтобы правильно работать с БД и чтобы она не тормозила

Comment: Просто для понимания, ваш вопрос выглядит как `зачем знать как пользоваться строительными инструментами строителю если есть магазины` — без знаний структур данных вы не сможете писать эффективный код.

Comment: На самом деле большинство программ (например, тот же браузер, в котором вы смотрите этот текст (или ОС, обеспечивающая работу всех программ)) вообще не используют БД для выполнения своих основных функций

Comment: У каждых структур данных - свои особенности, когда вы используете к примеру список из 10 элементов - вам всё равно, а когда вам нужно в режиме реалтайма связывать over9000 с over9000 элементов в многомерную таблицу с фильтрами по определённым критериям, вам ни List ни Array хватать не будет из-за низкой производительности. БД - это в основном для хранения данных, структуры данных более широки и универсальны, не только хранение, но ещё и эффективная обработка данных.

Comment: Даже банально к примеру вы с сервера ежесекундно получаете огромный список классов и выводите его тупо в dataGridView - 100% тормоза без знаний структур, которые помогут вам в оптимизации данного процесса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самым простым ответом на первый вопрос будет другой вопрос: "А где вы храните результат запроса к БД?". За ответом на второй вопрос лучше в гугл. А вот на счёт третьего: вы же по факту в коде работаете не с БД, а с результатами запросов к данной БД. Да и БД - способ хранения данных. И БД - не единственный способ хранения данных. Например можно хранить в txt файле или в json, что достаточно часто встречается.